# Spring boot with Minio Client:okhttp3.RequestBody.create([BLokhttp3/MediaType;)Lokhttp3/RequestBody; didn't exist error

Tags: spring-boot, minio

I am trying to connect to minio server by using minio client in spring boot. Getting this error:

> An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt
> was made from the following location:
>
> ```
> io.minio.S3Base.<clinit>(S3Base.java:104)
> ```
>
> The following method did not exist:
>
> ```
> okhttp3.RequestBody.create([BLokhttp3/MediaType;)Lokhttp3/RequestBody;
> ```
>
> The method's class, okhttp3.RequestBody, is available from the
> following locations:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.4/okhttp-3.14.4.jar!/okhttp3/RequestBody.class
> ```
>
> It was loaded from the following location:
>
> ```
> file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.4/okhttp-3.14.4.jar
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a
> single, compatible version of okhttp3.RequestBody
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tigerit.tigerhrm</groupId>
    <artifactId>tigerit-hrm-api</artifactId>
    <version>beta-1.4.0</version>
    <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>

      <!--  &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent &ndash;&gt;
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>-->

    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <other lib versions here>   
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

     //some_dependecies are removed to reduce the file size
       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${logger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

  <!--    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.minio/minio-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.minio</groupId>
            <artifactId>minio</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using java 8.
I tried without `com.squareup.okhttp3` dependency added in the pom.xml file too. Not working for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
Try overriding the `okhttp3.version` property in your pom and set it to a newer version of the `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp` dependency (4.10.0 works for me). Or just explicitly set this dependency yourself.
Or rather, if at all feasible, try updating your starter-parent version (not sure if this would work with java 8 though).

**Reasoning:**
The reason for maven (or, in my case, gradle) fetching an older version of okhttp library is the unfortunate pinning of this particular library version in spring boot dependencies in versions before 2.7:

```
<okhttp3.version>3.14.9</okhttp3.version>
```

In 2.7 they changed it to `4.9.3`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated my starter parent version.  Since then, it is working fine. My project was a kind of old project so there were lot of incompatibl libs which were needed to update too.

Comment: for the record, I did see that your question was getting stale, just thought I'd leave an answer for posterity since I stumbled on the same issue myself

Comment: I really appreciate that, someone might get help from this thread in future. cheers

Answer (score 0):

try updating spring boot version. I updated 2.3.2 to 2.7.0 and it works.